# Google Places Radar Search Leaving Out Some Results (not referring to detail information)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

When doing a Radar Search for a specific Place Type (in this case "shoe_store") the API is not returning all (within the 200 limit) places with the type "shoe_store" in that radius. It is obtaining some beyond the radius, but leaving out some within. More specifically the following API search is the one I'm looking at now:

**API CALL:**
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/xml?location=39.0923384,-76.8564899&radius=28967&types=shoe_store&key=APIKEY

Using a radius of 28,967 I should get "shoe_stores" within roughly a 18 mile radius. I specifically am looking to ensure I get "Shoe Show" and "Shoe Dept" of which there are 7 when one does a simple "Shoe Show near 14708 Baltimore Ave Laurel, MD 20707" in the regular maps.google.com site. However, when using the Radar Search only one of them shows up while other, further out, shoe stores show up.

Am I missing something in my API call or does the API simply prioritize results as it sees fit, skipping some and not staying within specified radius?

Comment: Does TextSearch return your "missing" results?

Comment: The problem with using TextSearch is its limitation to no more than 60 results (three queries of 20 with the pagetoken) and with the large radius we need it does not reach far enough, especially in high density areas. I did a TextSearch though with the same location however and one of the needed stores was found, but that was the same one that showed up before.

Comment: Have you noticed this behavior when you look for stores of a different place type?